# How can I send email from another group appscript webapp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

From my Web app, I am trying to send email from another person's email id. Is it possible? As getting the error "Invalid argument: piyush-team@gmail.com
at insertLog(Code:126)"
my code for email is

```js
var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var htmlBody = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
var body = " Thankyou for your response!! You have earned  by eating Fruits";
var subject = "Thanks for participating in \"Boost Your Immunity Challange!!\" - ";
  GmailApp.sendEmail(user,subject,body , {htmlBody: htmlBody, 
  name : 'Ministry Of Fitness',
  from : '<piyush-team@gmail.com>'
  });
```

When I do not define "from", it automatically sends the mail from the user's own name to user's email which is not the requirement.

Comment: Your code example is not a [mcve] it's incomplete, it has undefined variables and will not reproduce the problem.  Fix those issues and I'll consider assisting you.

Comment: Sorry I did not fully understood your goal. What do you mean by providing email "from name" as a groupid? Can you also provide an example input and possible output? aside from the minimal reproducible example mentioned by @Cooper

Comment: edited the code for ur referennce

Comment: Edited my previous question. Did you add this email as an email alias of the current effective user as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370)? to verify which email address you can use in the from option you can use [GmailApp.getAliases()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getaliases)